# Cut/Trim a mp3 file and send that portion to server in android

Tags: android, audio

I am Developing an application in android where user can select mp-3 from gallery and play selected mp-3.User can select a portion of mp-3 using Seek bar (Cut the selected part) and send the selected portion to server.
I am new in android development.And i don't know how to do this.
Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i used to search some one says that its better to use Ringdroid and there is no other way.

Comment: Are you able to programatically acces the MP3 file byte as an InputStream (e.g. FileStream).  If so, I have exactly the code you need to parse the original file into valid frames that can be appended back together to construct a subset of the original file.  As for getting it to the server, that should be an entirely different question.

Comment: Ya i can access the MP3 file, sir

Comment: Ya i can access the MP3 file, sir @ selbie